# App crashes with no error while taking a picture

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My app takes a picture, crops it, then plays around with filters before saving it using NSCoding. If I try to take 4-5 pictures in a row the app will crash with no error messsage. I really have no idea how to debug this. I'm guessing it's a memory issue but obviously there is no `release` in iOS 5 with ARC. I've added a picture that didn't tell me much but maybe it can help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app obviously (as the image shows) allocates more and more memory without releasing it again when it is not needed any more and you have quite a few (large) memory leaks.

Check your memory management and make sure e.g. image data that is saved to disk, not shown anywhere is also released.

Comment: What memory management should I check if I'm using `ARC`?

Comment: Using `ARC` doesn't mean you don't have to care or worry about memory management. You can still do things wrong. Instruments shows you where objects are created and released. The following article might be a start for you to learn using instruments to track down such problems: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

I know of two reasons this can happen:

1. Out of memory
2. You held off the UI for too long

For #1, place some sort of log operation in your app delegate `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, and also scan the console log for the (easy to miss) memory warning emitted by the system.  You will get a memory warning some amount of time before your app is killed.

I don't know of any good way to detect when you've been killed for #2, however.

But it looks like you problem is memory.

Comment: You also might want to read the article I linked in the comment above. You are mentioning two reasons why the watchdog is killing the app. Looking at the image above it is clear that the problem here is excessive memory consumption and the little black flag in the timeline shows when the app is getting killed. In addition, logging the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` doesn't really help, since this only tells you that iOS wants your app to free memory. There are other situation where this happens even though you don't have a problem AND it doesn't show WHERE you have a problem.

Comment: @Kerni - Right -- logging didReceiveMemoryWarning doesn't prove that it was a memory problem, nor does it point at the specific cause of a leak, but it does give you a strong hint that you have memory issues.  Unfortunately, there's no reliable way to log overall memory consumption at intervals, outside of the profiler, to get a feel for where it might be jumping.  But once you have the "hint", the profiler (though awkward to use) can point you right at the problem.